# Do pages that have received no traffic in a long time still have any SEO authority?

Tags: seo, redirects

Is there a rule of thumb for how to handle old content on websites? Should All pages that get removed have their URL 301 redirected to retain any SEO authority they may have. Or is it ok to assume pages that have had no traffic for many months have no SEO authority?

Answer (score 4):

If the page is not getting hit by users or even by bots over a few months it is likely not indexed and can be deleted. Even if it is getting only very occasional traffic, deleting it won't hurt the sites SEO.

Comment: What if it is indexed?

Comment: @Dan It wont hurt SEO.